# Program about getting breakdown in c#

Tags: c#, methods, operators, modulo

I am reviewing for my test tomorrow.. and I've encountered a problem in my program (I need to create a program that will display the breakdown of the entered amount.. and I am having a problem with the cents...)

```
Console.Write("Enter amount: ");
double amt = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

thou = (int)amt / 1000; 
change = (int)amt % 1000;

fivehun = (int)change / 500;
change = change % 500;

twohun = (int)change / 200;
change = change % 200;

hun = (int)change / 100;
change = change % 100;

fifty = (int)change / 50;
change = change % 50;

twenty = change / 20;
change = change % 20;

ten = (int)change / 10;
change = change % 10;

five = (int)change / 5;
change = change % 5;

one = (int)change / 1;
change = change % 1;

twencents = (int)(change / .25);
change = change % .25; //there was an error here.. starting here

tencents = (int)(change / .10);
change = change % .10;

fivecents = (int)(change / .05);
change = change % .05;

onecent = (int)(change / .01);
change = change % .01;

Console.WriteLine("The breakdown is as follows: ");
Console.WriteLine("Php 1000         ={0}    ", thou);
Console.WriteLine("Php 500          ={0}    ", fivehun);
Console.WriteLine("Php 200          ={0}    ", twohun);
Console.WriteLine("Php 100          ={0}    ", hun);
Console.WriteLine("Php 50           ={0}    ", fifty);
Console.WriteLine("Php 20           ={0}    ", twenty);
Console.WriteLine("Php 10           ={0}    ", ten);
Console.WriteLine("Php 05           ={0}    ", five);
Console.WriteLine("Php 01           ={0}    ", one);
Console.WriteLine("Php 0.25         ={0}    ", twencents);
Console.WriteLine("Php 0.10         ={0}    ", tencents);
Console.WriteLine("Php 0.05         ={0}    ", fivecents);
Console.WriteLine("Php 0.01         ={0}    ", onecent);            

Console.ReadKey();
```

The error said that I cannot convert double to int so I tried to convert it my casting it

```
change = (double) change % .25;
```

still an error..

Comment: Did you try to change `.25` to `.25f`?

Comment: yes still not working..

Comment: It seem two side of modulo expression must be `same type`. Or you need to overload it by yourself.  Refer: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/0w4e0fzs(v=VS.100).aspx

Comment: you can convert them, if they are not the same type..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDITED

initially make double change = 0 and and split the input amt to 2 variables

```
double wholeValues = (int)amt;
double decimalValues = amt - wholeValues;
```

then change

```
thou = (int)amt / 1000; 
change = (int)amt % 1000;
```

make it as

```
thou = (int)wholeValues / 1000;
change = (int)wholeValues % 1000;
```

Otherwise you will be removing the decimal values at this point

but you are missing a cast to int at

```
twenty = (int) change / 20;
```

modules by 1 will give the same value again, start cent calculation with the new variable decimalValues

```
one = (int)change / 1;

change = decimalValues * 100;

twencents = (int)(change / 25);
change = change % 25;

tencents = (int)(change / 10);
change = change % 10;

fivecents = (int)(change / 5);
change = change % 5;
```

if we use modules with decimal values you might sometime end up with incorrect values
for example for .30 cents, it will represent .25 cents = 1, .05 cents = 0, 
.01 cents= 4

Comment: cannot implicity convert type 'double' to 'int' an explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) that was the error but when I did what you told me.. another error like that added to the list

Comment: you are missing a cast to (int) at

    twenty = change / 20;
    change = change % 20;

Comment: no more errors but when i tried to enter the amount 1999.99 the .10 returns 0 value but it should be 2..

Comment: btw we don't have 30 cents in peso ^_^;;

Answer (score 1):

Use double change = 0; instead of int change = 0;

Answer (score 0):

finally got it!

```
int thou, fivehun, twohun, hun, fifty, twenty, ten, five, one;
double change = 0; // added this one as suggested

Console.Write("Enter amount: ");
double amt = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());


thou = (int)amt / 1000;
change = amt % 1000; //remove the int (change should be double)

fivehun = (int)change / 500;
change = change % 500;

twohun = (int)change / 200;
change = change % 200;

hun = (int)change / 100;
change = change % 100;

fifty = (int)change / 50;
change = change % 50;

twenty = (int) change / 20; //added int here
change = change % 20;

ten = (int)change / 10;
change = change % 10;

five = (int)change / 5;
change = change % 5;

one = (int)change / 1;
change = change % 1;

int twencents = (int)(change / 0.25);
change = change % 0.25;

int tencents = (int)(change / 0.10);
change = change % 0.10;

int fivecents = (int)(change / 0.05);
change = change % 0.05;

int onecent = (int)(change / 0.01);
change = change % 0.01;
```